# Creating gui binding for c++ and YUI

Tags: c++, jquery-ui, yui

I am planning to use yui or jquery ui  as front end for native c++ applications. I found no bindings present for this purpose. Will it be feasible/possible to do this ? If it is so, then how shall i proceed? please suggest advice.thanks

Comment: rwik: you are not taking into account that javascript APIs require a web browser and HTML and are desgined for client/server applications over a network with a server app and client app. They are miles away from being usable for a desktop application using C++.

Comment: @J.N. I guess you are miles away from reality. Just read brian's reply. Using webkit, I can do what I want, without a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rwik - I can see your point and desire to do what you intend and I would presume it to be a wise move to be making at this point in time considering the vast facilities browsers bring to the table as well as other aspects... I know we are in September now and I have come across this pretty late, but this is also for others who have a similar problem...

As far as I know, descending from JavaScript in to C++ is pretty murky, mostly due to the heterogenous nature of Javascript engines [Rhino, Tracemonkey, Spidermonkey, V8, Caracan,Charka, etc] employed by different browsers. But there are indeed ways to do this - depending on how dirty you want to get your hands and, indeed, on your abilities...

If you were to go with Google as a browser, you should take a look at projects such as cproxyv8 - http://code.google.com/p/cproxyv8/ or v8-juice - http://code.google.com/p/v8-juice/ which both offer interesting facilities...

My preference however is with Mozilla - simply because of XML User-Interface Language (XUL) which, if you do not know, allows you to speedily create your own user interfaces by giving direct access to its layout engine. I.e., you can even do away with the browser look and have your own independent layout while still having all browser facilities at your disposal.

With respect to C++/Javascript interaction - projects should exist for all alternatives - it pays to check.

I wish you good luck if you haven't already solved this problem.

Comment: Forgot to add - if you do decide to go the Mozilla route, you can take a look at XPCOM/XPConnect - which allows you to write components in C, C++, JavaScript, Python... Hopefully this is still the case... However, as I said before, everything depends on how dirty you want to get...

Comment: Simply fascinating. Will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend QT instead.

However since native C++ has nothing to do with GUI I'm going to assume you are making a library in C++. However Yui is basically just JavaScript as is jQuery. So if you're asking can a web page or script be a C++ application the answer is not really.

What you could do is create a web service which uses your C++ library and exposes an interface for your web based application to call it indirectly.

Comment: Can you elaborate this a bit "What you could do is create a web service which uses your C++ library and exposes an interface for your web based application to call it indirectly."

Comment: It's generally easier for a web service running in apache to load up a C++ library as a module. Then create a wisdl for each web client you want to communicate with the web service. Might have one for yui and one for jquery. There are limitations of course but this is not a trivial thing although it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to embed WebKit into your application and provide your custom C++ functionality via a plugin.  Both the WebKit framework on OSX and the Chromium Embedded Framework on Windows allow this style of application development.  This allows you to write a UI using local Javascript/HTML files without the need for a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

There are no direct bindings in JQuery and YUI because these libraries run in a web browser. Thus unless you’re planning to write your own browser plugins, the integration with the C++ will happen at the webserver that serves the data to the browser.

You could feed the data from your C++ code directly into JQuery/YUI by building web services directly in C++. But you might want to build a web application that will be serving your JQuery/YUI pages and that act as user interface controller (like in the MVC pattern). Web application languages like Java, PHP, etc. all have ways to call native code. Java has JNDI and in PHP you build extensions that link to C++ code.